# Form validation onkeyup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I am using this code to send value when user hits enter. What I want is if user hits enter without entering any value, he gets an error

```
<textarea class="auto-grow-input" onfocus="SK_focusChat();" onkeyup="SK_sendChatMessage(this.value,<?php echo $sk['chat']['recipient']['id']; ?>,event);"></textarea>
```

// Send chat message

```
function SK_sendChatMessage(text,recipient_id,e) {
    document.title = document_title;
    textarea_wrapper = $('.chat-textarea');
    chat_messages_wrapper = $('.chat-messages');

    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        textarea_wrapper.find('textarea').val('');
        chat_messages_wrapper.append('<div class="chat-text align-right temp-text" align="right"><div class="text-wrapper float-right">' + text + '<div class="marker-out"><div class="marker-in"></div></div></div><div class="float-clear"></div></div>');

        $.post(SK_source() + '?t=chat&a=send_message', {text: text, recipient_id: recipient_id}, function (data) {
            chat_messages_wrapper
                .append(data.html)
                .scrollTop(chat_messages_wrapper.prop('scrollHeight'))
                .find('.temp-text')
                    .remove();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try jQuery's form validation library. It works amazingly for this kind of feature. [http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: Can you post the code for the SK_sendChatMessage function?

Comment: I went through http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ but I'm unable to get my desired result. All I want is to prevent user from sending a blank message.

Comment: @BrianBolli I have added the SK_sendChatMessage function. Please help me solve this issue

Comment: _"I went through jqueryvalidation.org/documentation but I'm unable to get my desired result."_  ~ Really?!  Preventing a blank message is a primary function.  Simply apply the `required` rule and the message cannot be sent blank.

Comment: @Sparky please provide me the code. Sorry for being such a pain...

Comment: this.value (text in callback method) will return undefined when applied to a textarea since there is no value attribute

Comment: Provide you the code? There's not much to provide.  [Just follow the simple example on the Tag wiki page for basic usage](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).  If you cannot get that working, post a new question specific to [the jQuery Validation plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate) showing exactly what you've tried including the markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, use jQuery validation to check for empties. They have done a very good job with validation.

```
<style>
.error { color: red; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#omfg").validate({
        rules: {
            omfgdood: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            omfgdood: "Oy! It\'s Empty!" 
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php $sk['chat']['recipient']['id'] = 'omfgdood'; ?>
<form id="omfg">
    <textarea class="auto-grow-input" id="<?php echo $sk['chat']['recipient']['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $sk['chat']['recipient']['id']; ?>"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write your `SK_sendChatMessage` function like below.

```
function SK_sendChatMessage(text,recipient_id,e) {
document.title = document_title;
textarea_wrapper = $('.chat-textarea');
chat_messages_wrapper = $('.chat-messages');

if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == 0 && text == '') {
    alert('enter text');
}
else{
  textarea_wrapper.find('textarea').val('');
    chat_messages_wrapper.append('<div class="chat-text align-right temp-text" align="right"><div class="text-wrapper float-right">' + text + '<div class="marker-out"><div class="marker-in"></div></div></div><div class="float-clear"></div></div>');

    $.post(SK_source() + '?t=chat&a=send_message', {text: text, recipient_id: recipient_id}, function (data) {
        chat_messages_wrapper
            .append(data.html)
            .scrollTop(chat_messages_wrapper.prop('scrollHeight'))
            .find('.temp-text')
                .remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: I have added the current function. Please tell me what to edit and what to add. Thank you.

Comment: i have update your function,however you can change the alert msg.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:  First, at the very top of the SK_sendChatMessage function add this.

```
if ($('textarea.auto-grow-input').text().length === 0) {
    alert('Must enter text');
    return false;
}
```

Second, you're sending no data to your event listener callback by using this.value.  Since you are using a textarea verses an input, which does not have the attribute value to reference.  Which means all attempts to verify character length using textarea value will fail.

There are other opportunities with your code as well.  It is considered a best practice to not have JavaScript (or CSS for that matter) inline with your HTML.

You can attach the keyup event and very chat length like so:

```
$('textarea.auto-grow-input').keyup(function(e) {
    if ($(this).text().length === 0) {
        alert('Must Enter Text');
        return false;
    }

  if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == 0) {
      textarea_wrapper.find('textarea').val('');
      chat_messages_wrapper.append('<div class="chat-text align-right temp-text" align="right"><div class="text-wrapper float-right">' + $(this).text() + '<div class="marker-out"><div class="marker-in"></div></div></div><div class="float-clear"></div></div>');

  $.post(SK_source() + '?t=chat&a=send_message', {text: text, recipient_id: recipient_id}, function (data) {
    chat_messages_wrapper
        .append(data.html)
        .scrollTop(chat_messages_wrapper.prop('scrollHeight'))
        .find('.temp-text')
            .remove();
   });
});
```